# How to create specific lines around a JPanel rather than Border Lines?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, border

I am trying to create specific lines to separate panels from each other. The image below created in paint should help illustrate what I am trying to say. How can you do that?[image]

Comment: why you don't use border line? Seems border line meets your requirement.

Comment: When you use border line it seems to outline the entire perimeter of the panel space. That's is why I didn't want to use it. @zhliu03

Comment: What is the component used for the "Staff", "Stores", "Departments" ..? Are they JButtons? Have you tried JButton.setBorder()?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's a good idea not use border component, but you can make it by use `Label`.

for example, it's a case that 3 panels in `jPanel1` separated by jLabels

[image]

---

Example,

```
public class Ask extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 93, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 3));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 121, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");
    jLabel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 3));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 271, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 204, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );
    pack();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ask a = new Ask();
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.initComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: when I have used the border component but it usually wraps the line around the perimeter of the panel space. I want to control where the lines appear, is that still possible with one of the border components? @TomN

Comment: Also, I hand code everything and don't use a GUI system Windows, how can I produce what you did in coding. @TomN